# How can I return a JoinHandle from a function?

Tags: multithreading, rust

What is the best way to handle a situation like this:

```
use std::thread;

struct Prefe;

fn main() {
    let prefe = Prefe;

    start(&prefe).join();
}

fn start(pre: &Prefe) -> thread::JoinHandle {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Test spawn");
    })
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/main.rs:11:26
   |
11 | fn start(pre: &Prefe) -> thread::JoinHandle {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

I think I could use something like this, but I do not know what to use for `T`:

```
fn start<T>(pre: &Prefe, t: T) -> thread::JoinHandle<T> {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Test spawn");
    })
}
```

I see that `thread::spawn` uses this to return, but I do not know if this can help me or how to use it:

```
Builder::new().spawn(f).unwrap()
```

This seems to work, but I do not know if this is the right or wrong way:

```
fn start(pre: &Prefe) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Test spawn");
    })
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Review the function signature of [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html):

```
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
```

This says that `spawn` takes a generic type `F`. This type must implement the trait [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html). That implementation takes no arguments and returns an argument of type `T`. `spawn` returns a `JoinHandle` that is parameterized with the *same* type `T`.

To use this information, you need to know what type your closure returns. Once you know that, that is the type that your `JoinHandle` should be parameterized with.

Your example closure calls `println!` which has a return type of `()`, so that is what *this* `JoinHandle` would use.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation now I think it is clearer if return a `i32` For example it would only have to indicate it, thus `-> JoinHandle<i32>` O as an argument for `T`, Thanks for your time.